# How do multiple start screw threads have higher advance per revolution (lead)?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, material-science

> Single-start means that there is only one "ridge" wrapped around the cylinder of the screw's body. Each time that the screw's body rotates one turn (360°), it has advanced axially by the width of one ridge. "Double-start" means that there are two "ridges" wrapped around the cylinder of the screw's body.[4] Each time that the screw's body rotates one turn (360°), it has advanced axially by the width of two ridges.
>   [Source](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Screw_thread#Lead,_pitch,_and_starts)

Perhaps I'm missing some spatial intuition here, but I don't understand how can adding more ridges increase the advance per revolution without changing the angle of the crests. If there are two separate ridges instead of one, the nut would still have to go through both of them at the same time and hence would have the same amount of lead, no?

Or am I misunderstanding what "multiple starts" means here? Is it that the angle is increased, but to counter the effect of the steeper slope we have to add multiple ridges?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe this picture will help. I've "unwrapped" the (roughly) cylindrical surface of the screw, showing the threads in each case. The spacing of ridges is the same, but the slope is doubled in the case of the double-threaded kind.

[image]

When you wrap this back up again, the right hand edge of each rectangle joins up with the corresponding left hand edge.

Marginally related fun fact: decades ago the [Monty Python's Flying Circus](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Monty_Python) team released a [vinyl record](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Monty_Python_Matching_Tie_and_Handkerchief), on one side of which were two separate grooves, spiralling together from the edge to the centre. On dropping the needle onto the record, it would engage with one groove or the other, randomly. Playing time for either groove was half the expected time. They didn't advertise this "feature" widely; until people figured it out, it caused some confusion!

Comment: Thank you, that does make sense. However, wouldn't the added slope lower the prevention of linear motion due to gravity in vertical aligned settings?

Comment: Yes I believe so, the article that you cite states "the lead of a screw thread is chosen so that friction is sufficient to prevent linear motion being converted to rotary", and the lead is doubled for the double-start thread. This point is mentioned in this answer https://engineering.stackexchange.com/a/2027 (in the context of bolts) on the Engineering SE site.